# .qtip-vml{behavior:url(#default#VML)

Tags: css, wordpress, qtip2

I'm helping fix broken links on a friend's Wordpress website.  I'm new to plugins etc.

My question has to do with this .qtip-vml{behavior:url(#default#VML)

In a file commented as:
/* qTip2 v2.2.1 | Plugins: tips viewport | Styles: core basic css3 | qtip2.com | Licensed MIT | Sat Sep 06 2014 21:55:19 */

the last line reads:
.qtip-tip canvas{top:0;left:0}.qtip .qtip-tip .qtip-vml{behavior:url(#default#VML);display:inline-block;visibility:visible}

Xenu Linkchecker keeps saying #default#VML is a broken link.

My questions:

1. Is #default#VML a separate file she should have downloaded?  If so, from where?
2. Is #default#VML a separate file she should have listed (somewhere) in her website?  If so, where? -- Is there a specific folder where files like these should reside in a web?
3. If it isn't and shouldn't be a separate "file" in the website, why does Xenu report it as broken?
4. What should/can I investigate / do to resolve the "broken" report on this?

Thank you.